# palindrome checker algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, palindrome

i'm having problems writing this excercise. 
this should evaluate if a given array contains a palindrome sequence of numbers, the program builds correctly but doesn't run (console remains black). where am i wrong on this? thanks for all help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 15

//i'm using const int as exercise demand for it 
//should i declare size as int when giving it to function? also if it's been declared?
//i'm a bit confused about that

int palindrome(const int a[], int p, int size); 

int main()
{
    int a[SIZE] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    int p = 1;    //i'm not using boolean values, but i think should work anyway, right?

    p = palindrome(a, p, SIZE);

    if (p)
        printf("\nseries is palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("\nseries isn't palindrome\n");

    return 0;
}

int palindrome(const int a[], int p, int size)
{
    int mid, j;
    mid = size / 2;

    while (p) {
        for (j = 0; j < (SIZE / 2); j++){
            if (a[mid + (j + 1)] != a[mid - (j + 1)])  //i think i might be wrong on this, but don't know where i'm in fault
                p = 0;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

p.s.
how can i activate debugger "watches" on Code Blocks to look at others function variables? (i put a stop on main function)

Comment: you have a debugger (and print statements) for a reason.

Comment: Your program assumes that `SIZE` is odd.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need `while (p) {` loop. It is possible to have infinite loop here (and you have it!), because if you don't change `p`, this loop never stops.
2. You mix `size` and `SIZE` in the implementation of `palindrome()` (`mid` is half of `size`, but the whole loop is from `0` to `SIZE-1`).
3. Also it is better to move `int p = 1;` in the beginning of implementation of `palindrome()` (and to remove `int p` from list of it's parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
int palindrome(const int a[], int p, int size)
{
    int mid, j;
    mid = size / 2;
    for (j = 0; j < (size / 2); j++){
        if (a[mid + (j + 1)] != a[mid - (j + 1)]);
                p = 0;
                break;

        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an alternative without `p` where `palindrome` returns `0` or `1`

```
int palindrome(const int a[], int size)
{
    int j , k , ret;

    for (j = 0 , k = size - 1 ; j < k; j++ , k--)
    {
        if (a[j)] != a[k])
        {
                ret = 0;
                break;

        }
    }
    if(j >= k)
       ret = 1;

    return ret;
}
```

you can call `palindrome` in the `if` statement in `main` like this :

```
if(palindrome(a , SIZE))
        printf("\nseries is palindrome\n");
else
        printf("\nseries isn't palindrome\n");
```